# Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda3

Al ejecutar el script que muestro a continuación, me devuelve el error

```
Cannot perform 'rand_' with a dtyped [float64] array and scalar of type [bool]
```

¿Cómo puedo fijar este error?.

```
 df = pdr.DataReader("TEF.MC",'yahoo',"2016-1-1","2020-6-23") 

media_20dias = df.iloc[-21:-1, 3].mean()
media_200dias = df.iloc[-201:-1, 3].mean()
ultima_cotizacion = df.iloc[-2: -1, 3]

dif20 = ultima_cotizacion - media_20dias     
dif200 = ultima_cotizacion - media_200dias
    
if dif20 > 0 & dif200 > 0:
    print ("\nTendencia alcista")
    print ("")
if dif20 < 0 & dif200 < 0:
    print ("\nTendencia bajista")
    print ("")        
if dif20 == 0 & dif200 == 0:
    print ("\nTendencia neutra")
    print ("")
```

Comment: Hola! Veo muchas preguntas interesantes que vas publicando. Para tener más posibilidades de recibir respuestas sugiero intentar que las preguntas sean completas, indicando las referencias explícitamente (el error del título no es útil: copia el error en la pregunta). Del mismo modo, si haces referencia a otra pregunta de SO, enlázala. Finalmente, es bueno usar siempre la etiqueta python además de la concreta que estés usando. De lo contrario, estamos perdiendo mucha capacidad de relacionar preguntas y respuestas.

Comment: Ah veo que editaste para proporcionar una solución. En tal caso, lo que se hace es poner una respuesta tal y como se detalla en [¿Puedo responder a mi propia pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado la siguiente solución

```
df = pdr.DataReader("TEF.MC",'yahoo',"2016-1-1","2020-6-23") 

media_20dias = df.iloc[-21:-1, 3].mean()
media_200dias = df.iloc[-201:-1, 3].mean()
ultima_cotizacion = df.iloc[-1, 3]

dif20 = ultima_cotizacion - media_20dias     
dif200 = ultima_cotizacion - media_200dias

mask = dif20 > 0
mask1 = mask1 & (dif200 > 0)
mask2 = dif20 < 0
mask3 = mask2 & (dif200 < 0)
mask4 = dif20 == 0
mask5 = mask4 & (dif200 == 0)

if mask1:
    print ("\nTendencia alcista")
    print ("")
if mask3:
    print ("\nTendencia bajista")
    print ("")        
if mask5:
    print ("\nTendencia neutra")
    print ("")
```

En la consulta de Stackoverflow  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20333435/pandas-comparison-raises-typeerror-cannot-compare-a-dtyped-float64-array-with       se indica ".. debían encapsularse en () si se evaluaban en la misma senetncia. Por lo tanto, puede evaluarlos con anticipación colocándolos en otra variable o encapsularlos"